# How to use binding in directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my ng-repeat I have a directive called update which takes the current index of repeat. How can I pass index value to my directive ?

This is how my markup looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="article in articles">
         <span class="btn" update="{{ $index }}">update</span>
         <span class="btn" ng-attr-update="{{ $index }}">update</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('magazine')
.directive('update', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // restricting it only to attributes
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs.update);
        }
    }
})
```

When I run the above code it logs undefined. Angular docs on directive (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) says that using ng-attr as a prefix to an attribute does the job. But its not happening. I checked my DOM, when I use `ng-attr-<directive>="{{ $index }}"` as a prefix to an attribute it does not compile it to only `<directive>="value"`.

Is there something I am missing or doing it wrong ?

Comment: Try changing update="{{ $index }}" to `update="$index"`

Comment: This should work as it is. Maybe try and create a fiddle and share.

Comment: Hey my bad. It worked. I was on version 1.0.8. The download link on angular site gave me 1.0.8 instead of 1.1.x. Thanks man.